# Определение наличия запущенного приложения в ОС Linux

Tags: java, linux

Все происходит под OS Linux.
Есть приложение на java, которое научено мониторить на предмет запущенности, одно сетевое приложение(скажем, jabber-клиент) и при обнаружении оного выдает бесконечный алерт, который постоянно выскакивает до тех пор, пока не закрыть jabber-клиент.

- алерт препятствует навигации внутри java приложения;
- алерт выскакивает не сразу при старте запретного плода, а спустя рандомное кол-во времени (до 5 минут);
- алерт удается побороть **сразу** после закрытия запретного приложения.
- может, алерт выполняется и по какому-то ивенту, исключительно интуитивными способностями определетить не удалось, специальных способностей не имею.

Нужно научиться перехватывать ивент, который перехватывает java приложение, с целью недопущения вызова алерта. Ваши версии, господа. Буду признателен за любые мысли.

ps: это не борьба с такой властью "роботов" над человеками, это просто just for fun интерес.

**UPDATE:** Судя по первым комментариям, я пересолил с подробностями вопроса. Нужна не реализация алгоритма, а противодействие уже существующему, который работает по описанной схеме.

Comment: Может просто попробовать мониторить наличие jabber-клиента и убивать его?

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux"); 
получаем список процессов далее реализуем выше изложенный алгоритм

Comment: Скажите, greshnik, можно ли используя мудрость системного администратора 80 лвл запретить Java-приложении делать exec("ps aux") чтобы воспрепятствовать ограничению?

Comment: вы пользуетесь "жаббером" а у вас какое-то стороннее ПО перехватывает работу с сетью и выбрасывает все время алерт?

Comment: есть два приложения - I и II, когда запущены оба, приложение I возвращает алерт(который после нажатия на ок, всплывает снова) и таким образом использование приложения I становится невозможным. Если приложение II закрыть, алерт в приложении I закрывается и более не всплывает. Нужно: полноценно использовать оба приложения, без всяких алертов

Comment: Для начала разберитесь каким образом приложение 1 контролирует запущено ли второе приложение. А потом уже можно будет думать как решить проблему

Comment: А вам не приходило в голову, что, если у вас получится задуманное, то ни жаббер, ни ваше приложение не будет корректно работать?

Comment: Перепишите (или напишите) приложение 1.

Comment: я и прошу помощи в детектировании метода, которым может совершаться такая проверка, а также решения как его избежать. Именно от незнания причины мой вопрос и звучит так пространственно. Посягать на целостность приложения I и II возможности нет. Но есть рут доступ к ОС.

Comment: если пустить jabber-приложение от другого пользователя(банально от рута) то конфликтов между приложениями нет. Другой вопрос, что от рута это не престижно, да и рут у меня в виде исключения. Вариант с запуском jabber-приложения в песочнице SELinux не подошел, требует установки seunshare, а значит снова упираемся в рут.. Я так понял, что мне все ж таки к системщикам нужно обратиться. Я расчитывал, что может можно использовать какие исключения для жавамашины, чтобы не давала доступа java-приложению к информации о других запущенным приложениям.

Comment: Попробуйте тривиально переименовать jabber. 

Все равно находит?

Answer (score 1):

> Нужна не реализация алгоритма, а противодействие уже существующему

самое простое и логичное решение — не запускать то самое «приложение на java».

более сложное решение должно основываться на анализе исходных кодов этого самого «приложения на java», а ссылку на исходники автор, увы, не предоставил.

Answer (score 1):

Для отслеживания методик слежки приложения, можно использовать утилиту strace.
Для запрещения слежки можно использовать метод [LD_PRELOAD](http://habrahabr.ru/post/199090/) или какие-либо утилиты.